# Vimeo Froogaloop Events not firing

Tags: api, events, vimeo, froogaloop

I'm having problems firing and listening to events with the froogaloop api.
My code is :

```
$f('player').addEvent('ready', video.load);
$f('player').addEvent('play', video.show);
$f('player').addEvent('finish', video.unload);
```

And my function:

```
load: function() { $f('player').api('play'); }
```

And the video.show() function never starts..!
Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your player events inside the `ready` event.

So in your case, you can do it like this:

```
var player = $f('player');

// Listen for the 'ready' event
player.addEvent('ready', function () {
    // Now you can start listening to all other events
    player.addEvent('play', video.show);
    player.addEvent('finish', video.unload);
});
```

See the [Events section on Vimeo's API documentation page](https://developer.vimeo.com/player/js-api#events). It says:

> Do not try to add listeners or call functions before receiving this (`ready`) event.

Comment: For me, despite this, the finish event never executes. The ready event does however. Any ideas on that?